# Looping through http calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I need to make http call repeatedly after i receive the response from the previous http call and add a x seconds delay after getting the response of the http call before calling it again. 
What i have till now is below but i feel this can be improved.

```
var TestCtrl= function ($scope, TestServiceFactory, $timeout) {

    var onTestError = function (reason) {
        $scope.TestData = null;
        getTestData();
    };

    var onTestSuccess = function (response) {
        $scope.TestData = response;
        getTestData();
    };

     var getTestData = function() {
       // Wait for 2 seconds after making the call again
        $timeout(function () {
            TestServiceFactory.getTestData().then(onTestSuccess, onTestError );
        }, 2000);
     };

    //First time service factory is called
    TestServiceFactory.getTestData().then(onTestSuccess, onTestError );
};
app.controller("TestCtrl", ['$scope', 'TestServiceFactory', '$timeout', TestCtrl]);
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This would be a good scenario to use websockets. With them, you'd avoid all the http calls and simply have to send data every to seconds from your backend. The frontend can only listen for new messages and apply their data to the DOM

Comment: The service is already created and i don't have access to it. I need to make calls to get the data.